# Operations on existing Excel sheet using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files and I have merged the csv files and exported them to an Excel sheet.

Now can I add a new column in the existing Excel sheet where the result of the new column will be division operation of two columns existing.

Example:

```
col_new=col4/col6
```

I have tried to implement with csv files where after merging the files the final csv file would be like this:

```
col1,col2,col3
"1,200",14,2
"1,600",13,4

data=pd.read_csv(filename)

for i,l in zip(data['col1'],data['col3']):

    sah=i.replace(',','')
    sah1=int(float(sah))
    print sah1
    print type(sah1)
    data['res']=sah1/l
    print data
```

Expected:

```
col1    col2   col3   res
---------------------------
1,200    14      2    600
1,600    13      4    400
```

Comment: what is the output that you are seeing? what is the issue you're having?

Comment: I dint get how to do this operation on an existing excel sheet.I want to do the operation on the excel sheet directly where adding a new column and that column would be th output of divison operation on col1/col3

Comment: is this a `csv` file or `xlsx`? if it's a csv file, then I'd just read in the whole `csv` file, do the operation, and then overwrite the `csv` file. If it's `xlsx`, then I suspect you'd have to do similar and do all your computations in python, then load them back into excel.

Comment: but the issue with csv file is like i have a string in col1 if you observe . for which i am trying to convert as int but as loop is going output::<type 'int'>
    col1  col2  col3  res
0  1,200    14     2  600
1  1,600    13     4  600
1600
<type 'int'>
    col1  col2  col3  res
0  1,200    14     2  400
1  1,600    13     4  400
everything is coming twice need output as expected\

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the first column to an integer using `str.replace(',','')` as you have done and then use `pd.to_numeric()` to recast the entire series at once. Now that you have the two columns you're interested in as integers, just use the ability to divide one series by another and store that in `res`. From there, you can export it to a csv or excel file.

```
# set up the DataFrame to match your input
df = pd.DataFrame([["1,200", 14, 2],["1,600", 13, 4]], columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
print(df)
#     col1  col2  col3
# 0  1,200    14     2
# 1  1,600    13     4

df['res'] = pd.to_numeric(df.col1.str.replace(',','')) / df.col3
print(df)
#     col1  col2  col3    res
# 0  1,200    14     2  600.0
# 1  1,600    13     4  400.0
```

Part of the issue I see in your code is `data['res']=sah1/l` is saying `data['res']` is a scalar. So it will fill the entire column with that singular value rather than evaluating row wise. It will do this each iteration which is why you see the `res` column the same every time it prints.

Comment: final['res'] = final['REVENUE']/pd.to_numeric(final['Delivered'].str.replace(',',''))
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: well, assuming `col1` is `REVENUE` and `col3` is `Delivered`, you're applying it to the wrong column. If I'm mistaken, can you place the results of `df[['REVENUE', 'Delivered']].head()` in your question so I can see the actual data?

Comment: REVENUE  Delivered

   0.0          2

   0.0          1

  0.0         23

  0.0          6

Comment: I need col3 as 'REVENUE' and col1 as Delivered

Comment: Those are all integers and floats, so you don't need to convert numbers to numeric since they are already numeric. Please update your post with the headers and some values so that we can be on the same page.

Comment: but at the end i have the string values coming

Comment: A column can only be one type. If it's an object, then you can convert it as shown. If it's a numeric column (`int64` or `float64`) then you don't need to convert it. Please update your post with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may also be useful to provide the output of `df.info()` after you read it in.